# Missing definitions in bison autogenerated files

Tags: bison

I am adding a new rule in my exisiting .y file. Since I have not changed anything in the corresponding .l file, i am only compiling .y file with bison. Here is my steps:

1. Compile with command: `bison -d -l -p"glbSipParserAcceptContact" AcceptContact`. Bison compiles it and generates corresponding .c/.h files.
2. Build the library in Visul Studio, it gives me error that some tokens are not defined
3. Compare the auto-generated .c/.h file with its previous verion in the repository and i find that indeed those definitions are missing

I am not sure why! The version of my bison is `1.875` and the repository files have version `1.875b`. Is this the reason? If so, then where can i find 1.875b?

Comment: What are the errors?  What is your modified .y file?  Are you sure the older .c/.h files in the repository you're comparing with correspond to the .y file before your change and not some other version that perhaps never got checked in to the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Bison 1.875 is really ancient history.  The latest release is 2.6.5, and you should really update, at least to avoid having to fight ancient bugs (brr, sounds creepy).